# use regex in R to parse a string

Tags: regex, r

I have a string like this:

```
vmstat_webserver01.20130102
```

I need to use regex to pick the value between "_" and "."

I tried this:

```
grep("(_.*)+.", name, value=TRUE)
```

did not work any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `gsub()`:

```
name <- 'vmstat_webserver01.20130102'
gsub('.*_(.*)\\..*', '\\1', name)
```

Comment: you may want to use `.+` to indicate one or more rather than zero or more depending on the potential structure of your strings.